# Elo rating system alternative for non competitor vs competitor ladder

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm working on a ladder system that will have let's say 100 contestants pitted against each other. But these contestants do not battle each other as groups or individually. Instead, they battle each other based on their own individual performance.

For example. A beer brewing competition. Each beer made by each contestant is not being compared directly against another beer. But instead each beer will be rated on 4 stats. Taste, Look, Smell, Feel.

The problem is, some contestants may only submit 1 beer and some may submit a lot more beers.

If contestant #1 submitted only 1 beer but it rated really high in all 4 stats but contestant #2 submitted 6 beers that rated fairly high in all stats, if I just averaged for each contestant, #1 would win. In this situation it should be taken into account that contestant #2 submitted 6 beers in the same time frame.

I'm looking for an algorithm or rating system that takes into account the quantity as well. Or even if the elo system could work in this situation, some help on how to tweak / use it properly to balance the competition considering some contestants may have less submissions than others.

Comment: I'm not familiar with their exact rules, but this sounds like it might be a question for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the math behind the ELO rating system used in chess.  Check [the wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just have a rating for each beer rather than each contender. Highest rated beer wins rather than highest rated contender?

Comment: Based on my analogy that would work. But in my actual situation I need the averages of each stat.

Comment: @JustinCarlson ahh okay in that case. Could you not just take the averages like you said but then multiply the answer based on the number of beers submitted. For example if they summited one beer then multiple the average by 1. If they submitted two beers then multiply the average by 1.25? If they submit 3 beers multiply by 1.75 etc ?

Comment: that's not a bad idea at all. I'm going to run that with my actual situation and some test data to see how it pans out.